# How to use ng-repeat $index to find element in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

In my $scope, I have a property that's an array of cars appropriately name `$scope.cars`. User has ability to delete a car. I pass the $index (created by ng-repeat) of the car as a parameter to delete function `deleteThis`, however in JavaScript function where I receive parameter `$index`, I do not know how to use the index created by ng-repeat to find the car to remove from $scope.cars, since $index is not native part of $scope.cars. Please tell me how

```
$scope.deleteThis = function($event, $index){
   // how can I use $index to find car in $scope.cars to delete

}

<div ng-repeat="car in cars">   
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-1"><h2>{{car.name}}</h2>{{car.make}}</div>

<div class="col-md-2"></div>
<span class="delete" ng-click="deleteThis($event, $index)">x</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need to use index, you can just pass the object `car` and splice it out.

```
<span class="delete" ng-click="deleteThis(car)">x</span>
```

and

```
$scope.deleteThis = function(car){
   var cars = $scope.cars;
   cars.splice(cars.indexOf(car), 1);
}
```

You can use $index as well (but using $index is tricky when you have filters like orderBy or any other filter combined with the ng-repeat expression, $index might not be the real index in the original array). `$index` is not attached to the repeated object but it is attached to the child scope created by `ng-repeat`. Passing `car` is more readable and explicit as opposed to using $index and more reusable if you were to reuse the partial view inside the ng-repeat.

If you were to still use index, then just do:

```
$scope.deleteThis = function(index){
    $scope.cars.splice(index, 1);
}
```

Comment: Actually, if you pass car, I think it is still only the index (as my tests now seem to show). You agree?

Comment: @TomokoYamaguchi Yes in your specific case, but if you read my answer completely i hope i have provided the explanation as to why it is better to pass the object itself. Also if you were to use index, actually you dont even need to pass it, you could as well just do `$scope.deleteThis = function(){
   $scope.cars.splice(this.$index, 1);
}`. Even more explicit would be to pass car.id and look up and remove the car with that id, suits certain scenarios

Comment: I try to pass object car, but when I inspect it, it is only a number, not full object.

Comment: @TomokoYamaguchi Can you show me a demo of it please

Comment: @TomokoYamaguchi here is one simple example: http://plnkr.co/edit/oTDSJV?p=preview